# Set Columns and values in mysql statement from array

Tags: mysql, arrays, bash, loops

Is it possible to set the columns and values in a mysql query equal to a set of arrays that can change size and content? I thought of using a loop, but I realized I can figure out how to phrase

```
mysql -u$user -p$password -h$host $database<<EOFMYSQL 
INSERT INTO customers (${ArrayA[0]}, ${ArrayA[1]}, ${ArrayA[2]}, ${ArrayA[3]})
VALUES ('${Array2[0]}' , '${ArrayB[1]}' , '${ArrayB[2]}' , '${ArrayB[3]}')
EOFMYSQL
```

Idea of loop

```
mysql -u$user -p$password -h$host $database<<EOFMYSQL 
for (( c=0; c<=${#ArrayA[@]}; c++ ))
do
echo $c
INSERT INTO Customers (${ArrayA[$c]})
VALUES ('${ArrayB[$c]}')
done
EOFMYSQL
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: there could be a way, but wouldn't it be easier to just write a simple script in any one of the languages that lets you handle this easily?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this for working with arrays in bash...

```
fields=(field1 field2 field3)
vals=("val1" "val2" "val3")

nvals=()
# need to add the single quotes around the values
for v in "${vals[@]}"; do nvals+=("'$v'"); done
# keep the old value of IFS so we can reset it.  Of course, if this is
# being done in a script this may not be necessary.
oldifs=$IFS
# set bash's word separator to a comma so that is included in the expansions
IFS=','
into="${fields[*]}"
values="${nvals[*]}"
echo "$into"
echo "$values"
IFS=$oldifs
# this is just to show the expansion with the original IFS
into="${fields[*]}"
echo "back to regular IFS:"
echo "$into"
```

the results:

`field1,field2,field3
'val1','val2','val3'
back to regular IFS:
field1 field2 field3`

The array expansion with the [*] takes only the first character of the IFS variable (the standard bash variable used to separate words), so I was not able to add any spaces to make it more readable.  Of course this currently ignores fields that contain non-standard characters and values with embedded single quotes.

I also found I had to set the expansion to a variable (into and values) in order to get the expansion properly, I couldn't just echo the arrays, like

`echo "${into[*]}"`